# HTML/JS/CSS issue getting bigger by itself

Tags: jquery, html, css

[http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/4295/tableissue.png http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/4295/tableissue.png](http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/4295/tableissue.png)

Here's the picture to begin with.

I have this check box, that when you check, then with jQuery toggle(); it hides that you see in first half of the picture (#writeComment) and shows #SCtryVOTE (what you see in the other half picture, to the right).

Now i dont know why but of some reason it expands when its checked, why i dont know, is it because it needs more place than it have or? how do i make this work without having problems when its checked.

Here's coding:

```
$('#tryout').click(function () {

    $('#writeComment').toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));

    $('#SCtryVOTE').toggle($(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

the js jquery script part, heres the table and divs HTML part:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tryout">
<table  align="center" width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="theBoxer">
<tr style="background: #686868;">
<td align="center" valign="top" width="70" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">Opret</td>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="70" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">Opret</td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="70" height="112" style="">
TEST
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="70" height="112" style="">
<div id="writeComment">
Smid en kommentar:<br>
<form action="javascript:DoInsert()" method="post">
<textarea id="kommentar" name="kommentar"></textarea><br />
<input type="hidden" name="fID" id="fID" value="<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sæt ind!"> 
</form>
</div>

<div id="SCtryVOTE"  style="display: none;">
<form onsubmit="if (!this.comment.cleared) clearContents( document.getElementById('comment') ); return true;" action="javascript:DoSCInsert()" method="post">
<textarea onfocus=" javascript:clearContents(this); this.cleared=true;" rows="5" cols="40" id="comment" name="comment" <?php if($vis["username"] == $pusername) { echo "DISABLED"; } ?>>Tryk for at skrive. Skal være detaljeret og grundet.</textarea>
<br>Ja: <input type="radio" value="Y" id="SCvoteY" name="vote"></input>  Nej: <input type="radio" id="SCvoteN" value="N" name="vote"> </input>
<input type="submit" id="SCstem" name="Submit" value="Stem!"> 
</form>
</div>
```

Maybe you need the CSS part too for these two boxes:

```
#writeComment{
position: relative;
left: 5px; 
top: 10px;
}
#SCtryVOTE{
position: relative;
left: 5px; 
top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Umh, it'll help if you use a bit of indentation to pretty your code and make it a bit more readable...

Comment: Well, for starters, you've got an orphan </td> after the second "Opret" TD cell.

Comment: @Franci Penov Cant see where i should do this, which part dont you understand of the coding and i will try to explain the best i can

Comment: And secondly... there's a bit of missing code. E.g. Where's the checkbox?

Comment: @Gert G Oops.. thanks, but didn't solve my original problem

Comment: @Gert G Ops sorry but thats just a normal checkbox input with name #tryout, editing my question now with it

Comment: @Azzyh - my comment is not about "not understanding" your code, it's about "not being able to read easily" your code. using indentation to enhance the HTML readability will help a lot. while people on SO spend a lot of time and effort to help everybody, the easier your question to read - the higher the chances you will get good answers

Comment: Hello thank you guys for learning me, I won't be disagree with you guys because i know you're right, but I'll have that in mind for next time asking on SO. Please answer my comment on your "answer" you made Franci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `<textarea>` in the first form does not specify any size and the textarea in the seconf one does specify `rows=""` and `cols=""`.

Also, the increased vertical offset might be due to how you hide the first form. Can you post that script code as well?

Answer (score 0):

since we cant format comments

**re**: *@Franci Penov Cant see where i should do this, which part dont you understand of the coding and i will try to explain the best i can – Azzyh 1 min ago*

for example, **Which one makes it easier to see the extra `</td>`?**

**unindented (original code)**

```
<table  align="center" width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="theBoxer">
<tr style="background: #686868;">
<td align="center" valign="top" width="70" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">Opret</td>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="70" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">Opret</td>
</td>
</tr>
```

**indented**

```
<table  align="center" width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="theBoxer">
    <tr style="background: #686868;">
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="70" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">
            Opret
        </td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="70" height="25" style="border:1px #FFF solid;">
            Opret
        </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing is i dont know how to do these spaces while writing the code, i use notepad++, so i always thought that its such sorted up because other programs does it for you, no?

Comment: usually other programs do it for you. But you can do it manually as well, as long as your keyboard has a Space key. :-)

Comment: Yeah it is nicer when your tool does it for you, but if it doesn't, you should do it (for your own sanity really). Next is the spaces vs tabs decision :)